# QDockWidget autohide on start

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I have a QTDesigner dialog with a QDockWidget as main widget. When I dock it to the main window and show the dialog, autohides itself automatically but allows me to show/hide it using the mouse. I would like to maintain visible by default.
If I resize it using the mouse to a big size, about 2/3 of screen size, and close the dialog and show it later, it works as I want, even if I close the application with last big size.

Theese are my clases:

```
/** created automatically by QT compiler */
class Ui_OfsIndSelAttribBase
{
    public:
        QWidget *dockWidgetContents;
        QVBoxLayout *verticalLayout_10;
        QGroupBox *_p_gB_Filters;
        QVBoxLayout *verticalLayout_9;
        QVBoxLayout *verticalLayout_4;
        ....

        void setupUi(QDockWidget *dockWidget)
        {
            if (dockWidget->objectName().isEmpty())
                dockWidget->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("dockWidget"));
            dockWidget->resize(352, 789);
            dockWidget->setFloating(false);
            dockWidgetContents = new QWidget();
            dockWidgetContents->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("dockWidgetContents"));
            ...
        }
};
```

My dialog class tree:

```
class FCSDockableInputDataQt: public QDockWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        /** GetMainWindow() returns a valid QT main window */
        FCSDockableInputDataQt(Qt::DockWidgetArea do = Qt::BottomDockWidgetArea,
                               Qt::WFlags f=0) :
            QDockWidget("MyDialog", GetMainWindow(), f)
       {
           ....
       }
};

/** this is my dialog management class */
class OfsIndSelAttribQt : public FCSDockableInputDataQt, 
                          public Ui::OfsIndSelAttribBase
{
    Q_OBJECT

    OfsIndSelAttribQt() :
        FCSDockableInputDataQt(Qt::RightDockWidgetArea)
    {
        setupUi(this);
        setAllowedAreas(Qt::LeftDockWidgetArea | Qt::RightDockWidgetArea);
        setFloating(false);
        ....
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to make the QDockWidget hidden when the window is created but then toggle show or hide when you click a button somewhere, or something of the sort? Call QDockWidget::hide() in your setupUi method, then add a little toggle button somewhere that sends a signal to the QDockWidget when it's toggled telling it whether to show or hide.

Answer (score 0):

Connect QAppltion signal aboutToQuit() to your dockwidget's SLOT say onQuit:

```
QObject::connect(QApplication(), SIGNAL(aboutToQuit()), this, SLOT(onQuit()));
```

SLOT should look like:

```
void CustomDock::onQuit()
{
  setVisible(false);
}
```

So. when close your app, dock is hidden. If you start your app again, QT will restore CustomDock state to hidden.